# Is there a neat / organized way to edit the Chrome Search Engines list?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, search-engines

I really want to sort by url, name, or keyword in a spreadsheet-style list so I can make changes quickly. Chrome 6 on OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I can get the database import/export worked out [here](https://superuser.com/questions/226501/how-can-i-import-a-csv-file-into-an-sqlite-table-that-doesnt-allow-null-values), the way appears to be to open the Web Data SQLite database located in the Chrome user profile folder and then export that to an editable format e.g. CSV, edit that table, and then re-insert that information to the database. Thanks to [@Doug Harris](https://superuser.com/questions/223165/how-can-i-restore-my-chrome-search-engine-list-after-beta-killed-it) for illuminating this.