# How can I import a CSV file into an SQLite table that doesn't allow null values?

Tags: csv, sqlite

I've been using the SQLite Manager extension for Firefox to edit my Chrome web data file in order to restore my keyword searches, and I think I have everything in place except that when I import a CSV file into a table,

- it won't import into the actual table because the table doesn't allow null values
- if I import it into a new table that does allow null values, then all the empty strings end up as null and I have to manually edit the row, type and delete a character, and then it's set to empty string and it's fine

So: is there either a way to import the CSV so that empty cells are automatically turned into empty strings instead of null, OR is there a way once a table is imported that has null values to convert it into one that doesn't allow null values, where each formerly null value is the empty string?

Thanks!

Comment: if the values that are null are all strings, how about search/replacing all ocurrences of ;; with ;""; in the csv file ?

Comment: Weltenwanderer, put that in an answer instead of a commment. It's worthy of real votes.

Comment: I tried that and thought it didn't work, but it turned out the reason it didn't work was because of a different error message I couldn't read because the dialog flowed off the screen. I agree--put that in an answer and I will accept it, thanks! Though note that you have to search more than once because e.g. ,,, will only replace the first ,, and then ignore the next ,, after it's processed the first one.

Comment: added my comment as an answer, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values that are null are all strings, how about search/replacing all ocurrences of ;; with ;""; in the csv file ?